# State the following sequent as a theorem

Tags: logic, computer-science

$P \wedge Q ~\vdash \neg(\neg P \vee \neg Q)$

Not really sure how to do this, if someone could help me, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: HINT Since the goal is a negation, try a proof by contradiction.

Comment: What kind of proof system is requested for the proof of the sequent ?

Answer (score 1):

To prove $\rm P\wedge Q\vdash \neg(\neg P\vee Q)$ *by contradiction*, we shall need to show: $\rm \{P\wedge Q, \neg P\vee \neg Q \}\vdash \bot$.

If we assume $\rm P\wedge Q$, then ....

If we assume $\rm \neg P\vee \neg Q$, then ....

Therefore the two assumptions are a contradition.

Thus if we assume one we will conclude the other is false.

Answer (score 0):

What system are you using? I will do using natural deduction:

You eliminate the negation and get $\neg p \lor \neg q$ as hypothesis and need to prove $\bot$. Now you use disjunction elimination for $\neg p \lor \neg q$ and using $p \land q$ you get $\bot$.